# Three consecutive rows that equal 1 SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a list of names ,time , and event (0 OR 1) :

```
Name    Time    EVENT
AA  12:36:34 PM 1
AA  12:36:59 PM 1
AA  12:37:13 PM 1
AA  12:37:24 PM 0
AA  12:38:04 PM 1
AB  12:38:16 PM 0
AB  12:38:26 PM 0
CD  12:38:56 PM 1
CD  12:39:44 PM 0
CD  1:01:51 PM  0
X   1:03:12 PM  1
YS  1:04:20 PM  0
YS  1:12:50 PM  0
```

i want to find the names that had at least 3 consecutive rows (order by time) with event=1.

i tried playing with row_numbers but i can not reset it if a 0 enter in the middle . any ideas on what to do  ?

Comment: As a note:  The title says "equal 0" but the text says "event = 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this.  One nice way is a difference of row numbers to define the groups of consecutive event values that are the same.  One you have the group, the rest is just aggregation:

```
select name, min(time), max(time), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by name order by time) -
              row_number() over (partition by name, event order by time)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where event = 1
group by name, event, grp
having count(*) >= 3;
```